# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Я написал в инпретатор Python `import keras` и мне выдало ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Arigadam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from keras import models
  File "C:\Users\Arigadam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from keras.engine.functional import Functional
  File "C:\Users\Arigadam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 24, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
  File "C:\Users\Arigadam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import tf2 as _tf2
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tf2.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import _pywrap_tf2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.12.0
```

Comment: пробовал не помогло. Если что у меня Windows 11

Comment: Попробовал ещё раз помогло